# How do I switch visibility of a DIV in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, visible

I have a DIV inside my repeater as follows:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="topicView" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Delete_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table width="945px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="post-table">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="post-info">
                    <div class="post-info-left"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PostDate")%></div>
                    <div class="post-info-right">#<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PostID")%></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="post-left">
                <p><strong><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Username")%></strong></p>
            </td>
            <td class="post-right">
                <p><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PostBody")%></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="post-edit">
                    <p id="postEditAdmin" runat="server" visible="false"><a class="fancybox.iframe fancybox" href='editpost.aspx?postID=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PostID")%>'>Edit</a> | <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteBtn" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="javascript:if(!confirm('Delete this information? this will delete permanently'))return false;" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PostID")%>' /></p>
                    <p id="postEdit" runat="server" visible="true"><i>You must be an admin to be able to edit or delete a post</i></p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Can anyone let me know how to set the postEditAdmin.Visible to true and postEdit.Visible to false? It's not being picked up in the page load.

Also please note it's going to be changed depending on an if statement. This is what I have so far:

```
        if (Session["role"].ToString() == "2")
        {
            postEditAdmin.Visible = true;
            postEdit.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: Try wrapping each one in an <asp:Placeholder> tag and setting the visibility there.  (I'm thinking it could be multiple HTML server controls with the same ID that's causing the issue.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make div visible or hidden during binding process. Add event to repeater.

In aspx page, html side add

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="topicView" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Delete_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="topicView_ItemDataBound">
```

On server side code behind file add

```
    void topicView_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
    {
         if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
         {
           // Show or hid div here
           System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl postEditAdmin = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("postEditAdmin");

           System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl postEdit= (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("postEdit");

          if (Session["role"].ToString() == "2")
          {
              postEditAdmin.Visible = true;
              postEdit.Visible = false;
          }    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man. Only thing is "item" is coming up saying the name 'item' does not exist in the current context. Any ideas?

Comment: I missed that syntax it should be e.Item.ItemType, sorry about that. Check it now and tell me if you have any problem.

Comment: Hey @Adil. Thanks I did that, it's the "(Label)item" I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Modified my answer check it now please.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked. My only problem now is when I log out it's still set to visible. I added an "else" statement to reverse it but it's still showing. I'v set `Session["role"] = "0";`on logout for now, but is there another way?

Comment: Before logout set the Session["role"] = null and bind the repeater again. Do not forget to change this condition in ItemDataBound event   if (Session["role"] != null && Session["role"].ToString() == "2")
          {
              postEditAdmin.Visible = true;
              postEdit.Visible = false;
          }

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the postEditAdmin and postEdit parts inside a PlaceHolder control and set the visibility on that:

```
<div class="post-edit">
    <asp:PlaceHolder id="postEditAdmin" runat="server" Visible="false">
         <p>...</p>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

You could also use data binding to control the visibility to avoid code-behind:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder Visible="<%# Eval('PostEditAdminVisible') %>">
```

Comment: thanks but still coming up with the same issue. do I need to add something before the `postEditAdmin.Visible = true;` etc?

Comment: @dpDesignz Did you try data binding the visibility (see my second code snippet above)? That way you don't have to mess around in the code-behind

Comment: I'm not sure how to write data to the eval. I've never used it before and so don't know the markup for the cs file in C#. I tried following this but wasn't sure how to apply it to me. http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/04/05/asp-net-using-conditionals-in-data-binding-expressions.aspx. Could you please paste an example cs code?

Comment: @dpDesignz Eval is just shorthand for DataBinder.Eval, so you could change the code in your original question to `<%#Eval("PostDate")%>`, for example.
So, by adding a bool property called PostEditAdminVisible to your databound object, you'll be able to set the visibility using Eval without any code-behind.